# Ionic Cordova update issue with Android build

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, ionic3

I recently upgraded my Ionic CLI to v3 and updated my Android Studio to the new release as well.

I have a couple existing Ionic v1 projects that were building fine, even after the update, until recently.

My iOS builds fine, but for some reason, my android build is not working.

The error is  Error: spawn EACCES

From what I've read about the error, it appears to be a permissions issue that should be resolved by running "chmod 777" on the directory that shows in the error.

I've removed and re-added Cordova as well as removed and re-added the android platform.

But nothing seems to be working!

Below are the results of my android build command with the --verbose flag.

I was hoping someone a lot smarter than me might see something I'm missing.

Results of running build with --verbose:

```
Mac myprogram$ chmod 755 hooks/after_prepare/*
Mac myprogram$ cordova build android --verbose                           
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] to platforms/android/assets/www
  copy  www/index.html platforms/android/assets/www/index.html (updated file)
Wrote out android application name "myprogram" to /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml
android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (0.0.1): 1
Wrote out Android package name "com.freshconsulting.chainlink.myprogram" to /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram/platforms/android/src/com/freshconsulting/chainlink/myprogram/MainActivity.java
Updating icons at platforms/android/res
Updating splash screens at platforms/android/res
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
Executing script found in hooks directory for hook "after_prepare": hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
Running command: /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram
add to body class: platform-android
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-facebook4 for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/scripts/after_prepare.js
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Running command: /usr/libexec/java_home 
Command finished with error code 0: /usr/libexec/java_home 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mymac/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
Running command: "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle" -p /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram/platforms/android wrapper -b /Users/mymac/Documents/Projects/myprogram/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle
Error: spawn EACCES
```

Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: what does `ionic package build android` do?

Comment: [ERROR] Sorry! The configured backend (pro) does not know about ionic package build.

Comment: you have to chmod the gradle installation..Its actually a cordova bug. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve problem with:

sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-XXX/bin/gradle

Comment: Hi Sebastien, I tried your suggestion, but get: chmod: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-XXX/bin/gradle: No such file or directory

Comment: @cnak2 in your case it is `gradle-4.1` not `gradle-xxx`

Comment: Sebastien, maybe you could help me with another issue, somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397644/issue-with-compiling-ionic-android-platform

Comment: Actually, got it figured out. Cheers!